# Express server routes not being hit. Browser Error 'No Data Received ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having an issue with my express server with an email service I was attempting to set up. After troubleshooting I decided to boil it down and attempt see if the issue would replicate with a simple 'hello world' example, which it did. No routes will be work correctly each request, whether done by a js frontend, postman, or just in a chrome browser will work. Each request will just 'spin' until it returns a 'No Data Received ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE' error.

I've tried reinstalling the express dependency, reinstalling node itself, different browsers. The code is attached, any help would be appreciated.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

let port = 3000;

app.use(cors);

app.get('/testroute', (req, res) => {
    console.log('route hit');
    res.send('test success');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server started on port: ' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
app.use(cors);
```

to this:

```
app.use(cors());
```

Your server was hanging because you were passing `cors` as middleware.  But, `cors` by itself is not middleware.  When Express called it, it never sent a response or called `next()` to continue routing, so therefore the client was just left hanging forever waiting for a response.  Instead, the `cors` library is designed to that you call it as in `cors()` to get back a middleware function that you then pass to Express.

This is fully documented in the cors library [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#usage).